# Heroku sign in doesn't persist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So on my local host, the sign in persists and the user is signed in. However, on Heroku, after signing in, it doesn't even recognize that the user is still signed in.
In the heroku logs, it starts 
-A get request for log in
-SessionsController renders a new session
-A user is committed
-A POST request to start sessions occurs
-redirect occurs
-user sign in apparently isn't saved

-This seems like an issue with the cookie?

This is my Sessions Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
  if user
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    sign_in user
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
    render "new"
  end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to posts_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
  end


end
```

This is my SessionsHelper

```
module SessionsHelper
        def sign_in(user)
            cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
            self.current_user = user
        end

        def signed_in?
            !current_user.nil?
        end

        def current_user=(user)
            @current_user = user
        end

        def current_user
            @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
        end

        def current_user?(user)
            user == current_user
        end


        def is_admin?
            signed_in? ? current_user.admin : false
        end

        def sign_out
            current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token,
                                      User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token))
            cookies.delete(:remember_token)
            self.current_user = nil
        end


    end
```

In my user model I do save a remember_token before saving

```
before_save :create_remember_token
 def create_remember_token self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your code step by step:

1. A User is created with no remember token.
2. The sign_in method is being called. Nil is saved to cookies as User has no remember token yet.
3. Your current_user method sets @current_user to nil because User.find_by(nil) returns nil, and doesn't raise an exception as User.find(nil) would.

While I'm not 100% sure this is the reason why your code is breaking (as I can't see what callbacks you've written), it certainly makes sense. If in your local environment you create a new user from scratch I assume that it'll break as well. The only place I see you defining a remember token for the user is in the sign_out method - if you were signed in while implementing the feature, signed out to test it, and signed back in, the code would seemingly work.

This issue can be fixed by using a callback to set the remember_token of the User on create via callback, or in the sign_in method.

As a side note, if you're following Hartl's implementation of sessions, I'd definitely revisit that as you made a fairly large error in how you handle the remember tokens. The encrypted token should be stored on your database, and the unencrypted one should be stored on the cookie. Then when using find_by, you should be encrypting that cookie to find the user in the database. As it currently stands you're saving the naked remember token in both the db and cookie, which poses security issues.

Comment: Why would nil be saved to cookies in the sign in method if after creating a user I save a remember_token associated with the user?

Comment: If you have a callback in the model which is accurately saving a remember token, then I'm not sure - I don't know because you didn't provide that data. All I see is that in the controller it's not being done, and in the sign in method it's not being done either. So that's the conclusion I arrived at given the information provided. I would definitely poke around in Heroku's console. heroku run rails c. Then manually make a new user "@user = User.create(yourattributes)" then see if the user has a remember token "@user.remember_token"

Comment: Ah good call. I checked and the user remember_token is always nil. If I have  before_save :create_remember_token in my user model, and this definition for create (def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end) is there any reason why it's not saving?

Comment: The most likely reason is because you didn't allow the remember token through your strong parameters. I'd check there first.